# How to return a 404 for nonexistent WordPress http pages rather than 301 and then 404

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

Someone has created thousands of backlinks to non-existing pages of my website. Unfortunately, Googlebot tried to crawl these pages.
My website is in HTTPs. Googlebot hits the HTTP version of the page, my server first returns a 301 redirect and then, it returns a 404 at the second Googlebot query. It slows down crawling a lot. In fact, right now, Googlebot sees the 301 and decides not to follow the redirection right away.

I wonder if it would be possible to return a 404 before returning a 301 maybe by adding a directive in the Htaccess file. Meanwhile, I would like the server to return a 301 redirect to HTTPS when Google tried to visit the HTTP version of an existent WordPress page.

Example:
So, H T T P ://example.com/jdfjdfd/ does not exist. Googlebot visits it and returns a 301, and then my server returns a 404 when Googlebot visits H T T P S://example.com/jdfjdfd/
I would like that my server returned a 404 error page when Googlebot visits H T T P://example.com/jdfjdfd/

I tried to add the redirection directive after the WordPress directive but it does not work:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
rewriterule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

but it does not work.

maybe it can only be done in PHP with something similar to this with a modification in functions.php?

```
// add_action('template_redirect', 'redirect_core', 5000);
// add_action('init', 'redirect_core', 5000);
// add_action('wp_loaded', 'redirect_core', 5000);
function redirect_core(){
  if (!is_ssl() ) {
    wp_redirect('https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 301);
    exit();
  }
}
```

Comment: No, that will not be possible. With the kind of routing that WP uses, the web server passes _all_ requests that do not match a physically existing file or folder, to the index.php. WP then goes and looks into the database, to determine whether is has content to serve for the requested URL, or not. So on the .htaccess “level”, you don’t _know_ whether it is a 404, or not.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your shown samples, could you please try following.
Please clear browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
Rewriterule ^ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Keeping rule for applying https at top is always recommended.